# uefi boot problems when starting from dvd

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I am getting an error when trying to run an installation DVD in UEFI mode:

```
Failed to set moklistrt: out of resources
```

I would like to install in EFI mode. How can I get the DVD to boot?

Answer (score 0):

im sure this can help you
https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2015-10/msg02533.html
it's really old
disable secure boot in grub