# Ubuntu 18.04 UEFI boot fails: "MokListRT: Out of Resources"

Tags: boot, uefi, 18.04

When I try to boot my freshly burned Ubuntu 18.04 from a pen drive in UEFI mode on a Dell Latitude laptop, I get

```
Failed to set MokListRT: Out of Resources
```

In addition, I see some random colorful pixels appearing on the upper part of the screen.

In Legacy mode everything goes smoothly, and with the same burning method and configuration Ubuntu 17.10 also boots up without any disruptions – both in Legacy and in UEFI modes.

Is it a bug, a hardware incompatibility issue or am I simply doing something in the wrong way?

Comment: Related UEFI problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/943650/uefi-boot-problems-when-starting-from-dvd/943658?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating a new boot option, using `grubx64.efi` loader.

---

By default, [there weren't any EFI loaders selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUnR.jpg) on the installation media, so that's why BIOS could have some trouble selecting the proper one.

For others strugglng with the same problem on a **Dell Latitude**, here it is a short guide:

1. Enter BIOS setup.
2. Select **General > Boot Sequence** on the left.
3. Ensure UEFI is selected and click **Add Boot Option**.
4. Enter some name and browse for `grubx64.efi` on the right file system ([in my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqGwB.jpg) it was `FS1`).
5. Click <kbd>Ok</kbd>, save the settings and that's it!

Comment: I can confirm that this also works with Ubuntu 20 on a Dell Precision.  My fresh Ubuntu USB drive had been booting great for days until I finally connected to the internet and updated Ubuntu.  After updating I had this exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message, but a different underlying problem, so I thought I'd tack this on in case someone else winds up here.  My machine was also a Dell, but a different model (Optiplex 990).  BIOS navigation was slightly different, but the differences were fairly easy to navigate.

In my case, I had a machine with two drives, but was copying and changing them out.  I got the SATA data cables reversed, and it was trying to boot from the second disk which was not set up for that.

Two solutions worked equally well: create a new boot option as you suggested.  or just switch the cables back to the right drives.