# Ubuntu 18.04 UEFI boot fails: MokListRT: Out of Resources

Tags: boot, lubuntu, error-handling, moklistrt

I did wrongly given path permission in Ubuntu 18.04. Hence I faced lot of problem. So i backed up all important file, hence I want to reinstall the Ubuntu 18.04 using USB with the help of Rufus 3.0 method. After I reboot the system for install Ubuntu its showing error like "Failed to set MoKListRT: Out of Resources". I a new bee for this kind Ubuntu Installation. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029889/ubuntu-18-04-uefi-boot-fails-moklistrt-out-of-resources

Comment: Hi GabrielaGarcia, Thank you. Once it woks fine let you know.