# Ubuntu install media not booting on Laptop

Tags: usb-installation, moklistrt

When I try to boot a USB Stick with Ubuntu 20.4 LTS, it gives me this error on my Laptop:

Failed to set MokListRT: Out of Resources
Could not create MokListRT: Out of Resources
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state 0 failed
: Out of Resources

It boots normally on my desktop though.

The Laptop is a Dell Latitude E5420.

Comment: This is worth troubleshooting but meanwhile the workaround is simply disabling Secure Boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 UEFI boot fails: "MokListRT: Out of Resources"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029889/)

Comment: To ChanganAuto: I don't have an option for secure boot in the UEFI.

Comment: To karel: Nope.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Ventoy to create a secure boot compatible USB drive

this would also have the added functionality of allowing multiple ISOs on a single USB drive

NOTE: you have to ensure that you enable the secure boot functionality when creating the Ventoy USB drive.  Each computer with secure boot enabled that you use the Ventoy USB on will need to have the MOK registered the first time you boot to it, but that's simple enough once you've read the instructions [here](https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_secure.html)

Comment: I don't have Secure Boot though. I'll try it anyways.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work. The Ventoy menu shows but when I try to boot into the Ubuntu iso, it just shows the same error very quickly and then returns to the Ventoy menu.

Comment: check your BIOS settings for the SATA configuration... it might be set to IDE or RAID... make sure it's on AHCI